# How can I activate setState and snackBar on click of a single button?

Tags: flutter, dart

So, I was making a random tutorial app, and had an idea to use snackBar while changing the state of an app. But I am always getting an Exception: 
"Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold".

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  String _instrument;
  var _bal = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Text("Make Money"),
              ),

              Expanded(
                child: Text("Account Ballence : \n\$$_bal"),
              ),

              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text("Gamble"),
                        onPressed: _gamble,
                  )  
                )
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  void _gamble() {
    Random rnd = new Random();

    setState(() {
      _bal += rnd.nextInt(10000 - 0) - 4000;
    });

    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Money Updated"),));
  }
}
```

The Problem seems to be in function _gamble. Is there an alternative way to do this? I tried using Builder and return RaisedButton, but it was the same exception.

Comment: `Scaffold` has to be a parent of your stateful  `Home` wisget, not a child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If scaffold is parent widget means in one level above in widget tree then your code will work but if you want to use scaffold in same level then you have to use ScaffoldKey as following code.

Create scaffold key.

```
 var _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

Assign key to scaffold.

```
 Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Center(
```

Now Show SnackBar using ScaffoldKey.

```
 _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Money Updated"),
```